# Outlook undeliverable on copying to different mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

I use Outlook 365. I have two accounts with 2 different sister companies.

I have created a rule to copy the relevant messages from the second inbox to the first inbox, so that they are all accessible in one place.

One issue I am facing is that for the copied mails, when I reply, are undeliverable.

e.g. message is:

```
Your message to IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeLabs_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=e5ba949aded34c57b3ffd7276f316a7f-xxxxxx@xxxxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM couldn't be delivered.
Your email program is using outdated address information for IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeLabs_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=e5ba949aded34c57b3ffd7276f316a7f-xxxxx@xxxxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM.
```

When I see the recipient name in the mail window, and click on outlook properties, it is not correct Only display name is filled  with `/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group` :

> /o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=cc821ba918154595be3658baad4cbfa7-part name

I have seen a duplicate issue that does not seem applicable to me.

This problem I am having for a long time.

How do I resolve this while keeping the copying feature intact?

Also, I am not admin, but I can convey changes suggested to admins.

Thanks for your assistance.

Edit - Added Message Headers as requested. company name is replaced by yyyy.
Individual names are replaced with name1, email1 etc.

```
Received: from AM5P193MB0098.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:203:8d::7) by
 PAXP193MB1536.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM with HTTPS; Fri, 3 Sep 2021 09:42:51
 +0000
Received: from AM5PR04CA0018.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com (2603:10a6:206:1::31)
 by AM5P193MB0098.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:203:8d::7) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4478.19; Fri, 3 Sep
 2021 09:42:50 +0000
Received: from VI1EUR04FT006.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10a6:206:1:cafe::8b) by AM5PR04CA0018.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10a6:206:1::31) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4478.19 via Frontend
 Transport; Fri, 3 Sep 2021 09:42:50 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 82.135.112.202)
 smtp.mailfrom=yyyy.com; yyyy0.mail.onmicrosoft.com; dkim=none
 (message not signed) header.d=none;yyyy0.mail.onmicrosoft.com;
 dmarc=bestguesspass action=none header.from=yyyy.com;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of yyyy.com
 designates 82.135.112.202 as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=82.135.112.202;
 helo=mail.yyyy.com;
Received: from mail.yyyy.com (82.135.112.202) by
 VI1EUR04FT006.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.29.20) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384) id
 15.20.4478.19 via Frontend Transport; Fri, 3 Sep 2021 09:42:50 +0000
Received: from MFZERZIMP01EXC.yyyy.local (10.5.27.10) by
 MFZERZIMP01EXC.yyyy.local (10.5.27.10) with Microsoft SMTP Server
 (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.1.2176.14; Fri, 3 Sep 2021 11:41:56 +0200
Received: from MFZERZIMP01EXC.yyyy.local ([fe80::1148:26fe:9b66:c217])
 by MFZERZIMP01EXC.yyyy.local ([fe80::1148:26fe:9b66:c217%17]) with mapi
 id 15.01.2176.014; Fri, 3 Sep 2021 11:41:56 +0200
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_000_47e4dced156e4e6e9124e774134bffaayyyycom_"
From: Name1 <email1@yyyy.com>
To: Name2 <email2.ext@yyyy.com>, myname
    <mymail.ext@yyyy.com>, Name3
    <Mail3@yyyy.com>
CC: name4 <mail4.ext@yyyy.com>, "Name5" <email5.ext@yyyy.com>
Subject: FW:
 Subject
Thread-Topic: Subject
Thread-Index: Adef9WgkRJoADKhVTY+AyZRHxG94nwAsm+UA
Date: Fri, 3 Sep 2021 09:41:56 +0000
Message-ID: <47e4dced156e4e6e9124e774134bffaa@yyyy.com>
References: <AS8P193MB16547617B495EE84105A21E8A3CE9@AS8P193MB1654.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
In-Reply-To: <AS8P193MB16547617B495EE84105A21E8A3CE9@AS8P193MB1654.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
Accept-Language: en-GB, de-DE, en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-Mentions: name2@yyyy.com
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <47e4dced156e4e6e9124e774134bffaa@yyyy.com>
x-originating-ip: [62.216.215.177]
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OrganizationHeadersPreserved: MFZERZIMP01EXC.yyyy.local
Return-Path: email4@yyyy.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 03 Sep 2021 09:42:50.2221
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 88fb6bea-c83f-445b-b058-08d96ebf31c1
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Originating
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: MFZERZIMP01EXC.yyyy.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-CrossPremisesHeadersPromoted:
 VI1EUR04FT006.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-CrossPremisesHeadersFiltered:
 VI1EUR04FT006.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-OriginatorOrg: yyyy.com
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 88fb6bea-c83f-445b-b058-08d96ebf31c1
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: AM5P193MB0098:
X-MS-Oob-TLC-OOBClassifiers: OLM:8882;
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
 CIP:82.135.112.202;CTRY:DE;LANG:en;SCL:-1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:SKI;H:mail.yyyy.com;PTR:fw.yyyy.com;CAT:NONE;SFS:;DIR:INB;
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 03 Sep 2021 09:42:50.1592
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 88fb6bea-c83f-445b-b058-08d96ebf31c1
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 4684c455-93bd-4720-87cf-4e8591920c09
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalAttributedTenantConnectingIp: TenantId=4684c455-93bd-4720-87cf-4e8591920c09;Ip=[82.135.112.202];Helo=[mail.yyyy.com]
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource: MFZERZIMP01EXC.yyyy.local
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: HybridOnPrem
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: AM5P193MB0098
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.4114591
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.4457.024
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    ucf:0;jmr:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(750129)(520011016)(706158)(944506458)(944626604);
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    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
```

The copied and original message headers are identical.

The error that occcurs after sending the message from company xxxx is as below

> Your message to IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeLabs_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=e5ba949aded34c57b3ffd7276f316a7f-Name@INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM couldn't be delivered.
> Your email program is using outdated address information for IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeLabs_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=e5ba949aded34c57b3ffd7276f316a7f-Name@INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM.
> Rishikesh.Raje  Office 365  IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeL. . .
> Action Required         Recipient

> Outdated To address

> How to Fix It
> To stop your email program from using outdated address information, clear the recipient Auto-Complete List in Outlook or Outlook on the web by following the steps in this article, or by doing the following:

> • Identify the recipient who didn't receive your message by looking at the To or CC information located in the Original Message Headers section below. Recipients whose names are followed by a set of characters that start with 'IMCEAEX' or 'imceaex' didn't receive your message.
> •   Click New mail (in Outlook) or New Email (in Outlook on the web).
> •   In the To box, start typing the recipient's name or email address until the recipient's name appears in the drop-down list.
> •   Use the Down Arrow and Up Arrow keys to select the recipient, and then press the Delete key to delete the Auto-Complete List entry.
> •   In the To box retype the recipient's email address and then resend the message.
> If the problem continues, forward this message to your email admin. If you're an email admin, refer to the More Info for Email Admins section below.

> Was this helpful? Send feedback to Microsoft.

---

> More Info for Email Admins
> Status code: 550 5.1.11

> The recipient email address is a LegacyExchangeDN address, which isn't used by the Office 365 service. You might see this error if you've migrated your organization's email from on-premises to the cloud, or if your organization has a hybrid configuration and you synchronize your on-premises directory with Office 365. If clearing the recipient Auto-Complete List from the user's Outlook or Outlook on the web doesn't solve the problem, try to clear the related LegacyExchangeDN address from your on-premises Active Directory. Then synchronize the directory again.

> For more information, see Fix email delivery issues for error code 5.1.11 in Office 365.

> Original Message Details
> Created Date:   6/11/2021 11:52:00 AM
> Sender Address: Rishikesh.Raje@xxxx.com

> Recipient Address:    IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeLabs_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=e5ba949aded34c57b3ffd7276f316a7f-Boopathiraj@INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
> Subject:    SW Controller Test timeline

> Error Details
> Reported error: 550 5.1.11 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; Recipient not found by Exchange Legacy encapsulated email address lookup
> DSN generated by:   BMXPR01MB4869.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM

> Message Hops
> HOP TIME (UTC)  FROM    TO  WITH    RELAY TIME
> 1   6/11/2021
> 11:52:00 AM BM1PR01MB3172.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM BM1PR01MB3172.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM mapi    *
> 2   6/11/2021
> 11:52:01 AM BM1PR01MB3172.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM BMXPR01MB4869.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)    1 sec
> Original Message Headers

---

My Anaylsis based on your inputs
The company yyyy is using LegacyDN addresses, while company xxxx is using Office365 addresses. So Copying mail from company yyyy to company xxxx is causing this error.

Is this correct as per your understanding?

Comment: Could you add to your post a dump of the message headers of one such message, both before and after the copy?

Comment: There is lot of private information in the message headers. Can you tell me which part do you need, or is there some way to strip identifiable info.

Comment: I would mostly like to see the headers of: Return-Path, Received, Message-ID, From, To. You may replace sensitive data by XXXX, YYYY etc, just be consistent as regarding before/after.

Comment: The headers are identical in the copied and original mail. I will remove identifiable names and addresses, but IP addresses still remain.

Comment: @harrymc I have updated the headers in the post

Comment: Can also add the full error that you get if you reply to this message?

Comment: ... and afterward check if [this method](https://medium.com/365uc/imceaex-ndrs-and-how-to-solve-them-9876dec3537) helps.

Comment: Did you try my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I could make a copy of messages from a mailbox to another and reply them normally in Outlook.

According to your description, the issue may be related to the recipient's address. Did this issue occur on all messages that you moved? And could it be reproduced if you re-type the recipient's address manually?

Based on my experience, any incorrect Auto-complted items may cause it, it's recommended to empty the auto-complete list in 2 mailboxes to check.

Comment: I have emptied the auto complete list once or twice before. Same issue crops up.  Is it possible that the issue is related to come inconsistency between two mailboxes. If known I can ask IT to fix it.

Comment: Tp answer your questions. "Did this issue occur on all messages that you moved?" -- Almost all .   "And could it be reproduced if you re-type the recipient's address manually?" -- Yes, it is reproduced in auto complete list. Only on clearing the auto complete list and selecting from address book, isssue is resolved.

Comment: Looks like it's related to the auto-complete, are your accounts all in exchange server? If so, I found a similar thread that mentioned it may be related to the x500 address,for your reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outdated-address-information-for-recipients/579e5adb-2354-4a7c-a2ba-12261f4ccdfe
In this case, maybe you could try to contact your exchange administrator to check.

Comment: I have again emptied the autocomplete list. Will check for recurrrence. Buut I believe this will occur again, and is because of incompatible mailboxes. And FYI I am applying rule to move the messages.